# User adding answers linking to his own site everywhere

Tags: support, hyperlinks, user-accounts

So I've come across this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1875976/adrian)

**All** his answers link to his own site and provide no further explanation. Should I just flag all the answers?

I have flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18285480/542251) and provided some feedback. But this *seemed* like it's a bit more serious as it appears to me, he's doing this for SEO.

**Edit**
Sorry the link didn't originally go to the actual user!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is self-promoting and considered as spam. Flag as such.

If a user has more than only one self-promoting post then you can flag the *other* reason and explain the matter.